# Power-series expansion of $\mathrm{e}^{\frac{z}{2}(t-\frac{1}{t})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, exponentiation, factorial

I would like to know the procedure to do the power-series expansion of this function:

$$\LARGE{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{z}{2}(t-\frac{1}{t})}}$$

so that I would get this:

$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty \sum_{s=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^s z^{r+s} t^{r-s}}{r!s!2^{r+s}}$$

I was unable to obtain this double series and the only thing I know is this basic formula:

$$\mathrm{e}^z=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}$$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150030/discussion-on-question-by-user122424-power-series-expansion-of-mathrme-fra); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to use the exponential series and Newton's binomial theorem, before swapping the summation indexes, as follows :
$$
\begin{array}{rcll}
\displaystyle e^{\frac{z}{2}\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)}
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^nn!} \left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)^n & (1) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^nn!} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} t^k (-t^{-1})^{n-k} & (2) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{n-k} z^n t^{2k-n}}{2^n(n-k)!k!} & (*) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-k} z^n t^{2k-n}}{2^n(n-k)!k!} & (3) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(m+k)-k} z^{m+k} t^{2k-(m+k)}}{2^{m+k}((m+k)-k)!k!} & (4) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m z^{k+m} t^{k-m}}{2^{k+m}k!m!}
\end{array}
$$
where we used (1) the exponential series, (2) the binomial theorem, (3) a swap of the two sums and (4) an index shift such that $n := m+k$.

Alternatively, you may take advantage of Cauchy product formula, namely
$$
\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i\right) \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k},
$$
so that
$$
e^{\frac{z}{2}\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)} 
   = e^{zt/2}e^{-z/2t} 
   = \left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{z^it^i}{2^ii!}\right) \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j\frac{z^jt^{-j}}{2^jj!}\right)
$$
and you will end up to the step $(*)$ above.

---

**Addendum.**
The step going from $(*)$ to $(3)$ is made by inverting the order of summation. It cannot be done freely since the index $k$ depends on $n$ as an upper bound. It is to be noted that $k$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, like $n$, but the index $n$ must increase for $k$ to reach higher values, because $k \le n$. This point of view can be reversed by saying that $k$ goes effectively from to $0$ to $\infty$ as a free variable and then $n$ takes all the values above $k$ (since $n \ge k$), namely from $k$ to $\infty$. This fact translates as
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \longleftrightarrow \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty
$$

Comment: Good. I do not follow $(3)$ yet. Could you give me a hint to this point ? Thank you.

Comment: @user122424  I've edited my answer in order to include the hint you requested. You're welcome ;)

Comment: Mind boggling but nice. Does it hold: $$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty
$$ in general ?

Comment: @user122424  Yes, it does, because $n$ and $k$ are independent of each other in that case. Another way to see the swapped summations in my answer is as follows : you can list all the pairs $(n,k)$ in a (triangular) table, so that one order of summation goes by adding one row after another, when the second order follows the columns. This swapping is actually the discrete analog of a two-dimensional integration over a triangular domain in calculus.

Comment: How I prove the Cauchy product formula
$$
\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i\right) \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k},
$$ along the lines as **Addendum** ? I've got this hint: Arrange the terms in a table like this:
$$
\begin{array}{ cccccc }
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \kern3mu\raise1mu{.}\kern3mu\raise6mu{.}\kern3mu\raise12mu{.} \\ 
  a_3b_0 & a_3b_1 & a_3b_2 & a_3b_3 & \dots \\
  a_2b_0 & a_2b_1 & a_2b_2 & a_2b_3 & \dots \\
  a_1b_0 & a_1b_1 & a_1b_2 & a_1b_3 & \dots \\
  a_0b_0 & a_0b_1 & a_0b_2 & a_0b_3 & \dots \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: What should I notice about the diagonals to prove the Cauchy product formula ?